# How can I edit My image EXIF data for image rotation

Tags: android, android-camera

In my app the user gets an image from the camera or gallery, these images are then converted to a PDF Now my Problem is on some devices the image captured by the Camera is rotated 90 degrees, the devices are some samsung devices specifically an S7,

I know I need to edit the EXIF data of the image but I am new to android, and the entire EXIF data thing goes over my head completely any help would be aprecieated

This is where I call the selected image and convert it to a PDF

```
  PdfDocument document=new PdfDocument();
    // crate a page description
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo;
    PdfDocument.Page page;
    Canvas canvas;
    int i;
```

Bitmap image;

```
    for (i=0; i < list.size(); i++)  {


        pageInfo=new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(992, 1432, 1).create();
        page=document.startPage(pageInfo);
        canvas=page.getCanvas();
        image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(i));
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 980, 1420, true);
        image.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300);
        canvas.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300);
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
        document.finishPage(page);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") String directory_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mypdf/";
        File file=new File(directory_path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp=(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")).format(new Date());
        String targetPdf=directory_path + timeStamp + ".pdf";
        File filePath=new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("main", "error " + e.toString());
            Toasty.error(this, "Error making PDF" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // close the document
        document.close();
```

Comment: please accept and upvote my answer if it works, please note that your generated pdf will not be saved in android 10 as it uses scoped storage for external storage access

Comment: Thanks dude, It Won't matter as my client base won't really need access to the ones stored on the phone itself as my servers mail it to them anyways, Its more of a nice to have and not an essential part of the app, But thanks for the Heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your build gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
```

get rotation data:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
         ExifInterface exif;
                        try {
                            exif = new ExifInterface(path);
                            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                             Bitmap bmRotated = MyUtility.rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);
}
 } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

rotateBitmap() method:

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                mLog.i(TAG,"normal");
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                mLog.i(TAG,"ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL");
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                mLog.i(TAG,"ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180");
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                mLog.i(TAG,"ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL");
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                mLog.i(TAG,"ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE");
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                mLog.i(TAG,"ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90");
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                mLog.i(TAG,"ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE");
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                mLog.i(TAG,"ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270");
                break;

            default:
                mLog.i(TAG,"UNKNOWN");
                return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Although I have had problems on a few samsung devices this works well. Give it a try.